# Responsive obtuse-angled triangle css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been searching for answers about this.

Is it possible to make an responsive obtuse-angled triangle in html/css or JS?

I would like to make a triangle such as this:

obtuse-angled triangle example :

[image]

I do know how to make triangles with the border trick, but i can't figure out how to make the otuse-angled one.

I hope you guys can help and have a smart trick.

Best regards
Joachim

Comment: Please share the code of what you tried, create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simply way using linear-gradient:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100px;
  background:linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%, blue 51%) 0 0/20% 100% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%, blue 51%) 100% 0/calc(80% + 1px) 100% no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This really helped. I tried with the gradient, but couldn't figure out how to manage it. Now you have helped me to see how i can work with the gradient further on (Y)

Comment: @JoachimSchubert the main idea is to rely on multiple gradient and as you can see each one will take a part of the element ... one will take 20% and the other 80% this is the trick :) And you can go with more and more gradient in the same element

Answer (score 0):

Use borders of different widths

```css
div {
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 250px 250px 0px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I made it with the gradient background instead, but i apreciate your help and i hope other people with the same issue as me, can use this answer later on! :-)